# SQL SUM and GROUP BY based on WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.4 and have the following table structure for invoicing:

```
id BIGINT, time UNIX_TIMESTAMP, customer TEXT, amount BIGINT, status TEXT, billing_id TEXT
```

I hope I can explain my challenge correctly.

A invoice record can have 2 different status; `begin`, `ongoing` and `done`.
Several invoice records can be part of the same invoice line, over time.

So when an invoice period begins, a record is started with status `begin`.
Then every 6 hour there will be generated a new record with status `ongoing` containing the current amount spend in `amount`.
When an invoice is closed a record with status `done` is generated with the total amount spend in column `amount`. All the invoice records within the same invoice contains the same `billing_id`.

To calcuate a customers current spendings I can run the following:

```
SELECT sum(amount) FROM invoice_records where id = $1 and time between '2017-06-01' and '2017-07-01' and status = 'done'
```

But that does not take into account if there's an ongoing invoice which are not closed yet.

How can I also count the largest billing_id with no status `done`?

Hope it make sense.

Comment: Why are you doing `sum()` if there is only one `status = 'done'` per `id`? Wouldn't just `SELECT amount FROM` suffice or I missed something?

Comment: In my example I'm summarizing all invoices for a specific customer (ìd`).

Comment: You call the customer ID just ID in this table? You shouldn't. A column called ID should uniquely identify a record in the table. If you want a customer ID in that table, then call it customer_id or the like.

Comment: I agree, unfortunately it's not my table, and I'm unable to change anything in it :( But agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per invoice (i.e. `billing_id`) you want the amount of the record with `status = 'done'` if such exists or of the last record with `status = 'ongoing'`. You can use PostgreSQL's `DISTINCT ON` for this (or use standard SQL's `ROW_NUMBER` to rank the records per invoice).

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (billing_id) billing_id, amount
FROM invoice_records 
WHERE status IN ('done', 'ongoing', 'begin')
ORDER BY 
  billing_id, 
  CASE status WHEN 'done' THEN 1 WHEN 'ongoing' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END,
  unix_timestamp desc;
```

The `ORDER BY` clause represents the ranking.

Comment: The same `billing_id` can contain 1 `begin`, X `ongoing`and 1 `done` records. `begin`may also contain `amount` and there can be several 10+ records with `ongoing`.

Comment: Okay, so you are also interested in status = 'begin'. That's a simple change. As to 1 done and x ongoing: I know. This is why I pick one record per billing_id; preferrably the 1 done, else the latest ongoing. I'll update to take status = begin into account.

Comment: What does `DISTINCT ON (billing_id), billing_id` do, seems dublicate?
I'm getting syntax error at or near ","` near `SELECT DISTINCT ON (billing_id), billing_id`

Comment: Oh, sorry the comma doesn't belong. It must `DISTINCT ON (billing_id) billing_id`. `DISTINCT ON (billing_id)` says I want one result row per `billing_id`. And `billing_id` says, I want to see this column in my results.

Comment: Ah, I see. Now I'm getting: `column "invoice_records.billing_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: That doesn't make sense. There is no aggregation in the query. No `SUM`, no `MAX`, ... So why does the DBMS complain? You must have changed my query somehow.

Comment: Sorry, yes... Works now... Ran a wrong query. Thank you so much,. really helpful and understandable.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to also simply `order by billing_id, amount desc, unix_timestamp desc` as amount always will be incremental?

Comment: If amount is always incremental, then you want the row with the highest amount. So yes, in that case that order would suffice. (And if you are only interested in the amount, then you don't have to deal with ties either and can remove `, unix_timestamp desc` from that clause, too.)

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum (amount), id
from (
    select distinct on (billing_id) *
    from (
        select distinct on (status, billing_id) *
        from invoice_records
        where
            id = $1
            and time between '2017-06-01' and '2017-07-01'
            and status in ('done', 'ongoing')
        order by status, billing_id desc
    ) s
    order by billing_id desc
) s
```